# Efficient browser `StorageEvent` handling

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, browser-storage

I have this class `EfficientStorageEventProvider`, which is responsible for efficient handling of `StorageEvent`

`EfficientStorageEventProvider.ts`

```js
import { IStorageEventRecord } from "./IStorageEventRecord";
import { defer, Observable, share, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { doOnSubscriberCountChange } from "rx-do-on-subscriber-count-change";
import { isDefined, isUndefined } from "is-null";

/**
 * {@link EfficientStorageEventProvider} is responsible for:
 * - Efficient `"storage"` event handling
 * (1 check if key is in map of observed keys per `StorageEvent`,
 * instead of having `key_count` checks in every event listener
 * if we should handle event with this key in current handler)
 */
export class EfficientStorageEventProvider {
  private _observedKeyCount = 0;

  private readonly _observedKeyToStorageEventRecordMap = new Map<
    string,
    IStorageEventRecord
  >();

  private readonly _handleStorageEvent: (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => void;

  constructor() {
    this._handleStorageEvent = (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => {
      if (storageEvent.key !== null) {
        const storageEventRecord = this._observedKeyToStorageEventRecordMap.get(
          storageEvent.key,
        );

        if (isDefined(storageEventRecord)) {
          storageEventRecord.storageEventS.next(storageEvent);
        }
      } else {
        // If `key` is `null`, user requested to delete all items
        this._observedKeyToStorageEventRecordMap.forEach(
          (storageEventRecord2) => {
            storageEventRecord2.storageEventS.next(storageEvent);
          },
        );
      }
    };
  }

  /**
   * Notice that order of events is not guaranteed,
   * and following from it, not all events may be processed at all!,
   * because see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969202/in-which-order-storage-event-is-received
   */
  getStorageEventForKey$(key: string): Observable<StorageEvent> {
    return defer(() => {
      let storageEventRecord =
        this._observedKeyToStorageEventRecordMap.get(key);

      if (isUndefined(storageEventRecord)) {
        const storageEventS = new Subject<StorageEvent>();
        const storageEvent$ = storageEventS.pipe(
          doOnSubscriberCountChange((newSubscriberCount) => {
            if (newSubscriberCount === 1) {
              this._tryStartListeningStorageEvent();
            } else if (newSubscriberCount === 0) {
              this._observedKeyToStorageEventRecordMap.delete(key);
              this._tryStopListeningStorageEvent();
            }
          }),
          share(),
        );

        storageEventRecord = {
          storageEvent$,
          storageEventS,
        };

        this._observedKeyToStorageEventRecordMap.set(key, storageEventRecord);
      }

      return storageEventRecord.storageEvent$;
    });
  }

  private _tryStartListeningStorageEvent() {
    if (++this._observedKeyCount === 1) {
      window.addEventListener("storage", this._handleStorageEvent);
    }
  }

  private _tryStopListeningStorageEvent() {
    if (--this._observedKeyCount === 0) {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", this._handleStorageEvent);
    }
  }
}
```

`doOnSubscriberCountChange.ts`

```js
import { Observable, OperatorFunction, Subscriber } from "rxjs";

export function doOnSubscriberCountChange<TValue>(
  handleNewSubscriberCount: (newSubscriberCount: number) => void,
): OperatorFunction<TValue, TValue> {
  return (source$) => {
    let subscriberCount = 0;

    return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<TValue>) => {
      const subscription = source$.subscribe(subscriber);
      handleNewSubscriberCount(++subscriberCount);

      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        handleNewSubscriberCount(--subscriberCount);
      };
    });
  };
}
```

`IStorageEventRecord.ts`

```js
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

export interface IStorageEventRecord {
  storageEvent$: Observable<StorageEvent>;
  storageEventS: Subject<StorageEvent>;
}
```

How can we improve it from point of view of performance/correctness/helpful-comments/more-representative-names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rxjs` has a steep learning curve, and it is difficult to explain to people how this code works or why it is correct.

Removing `rxjs` significantly eased understanding of this code, even by newer members of our team.

```js
import { isDefined, isUndefined } from "is-null";

/**
 * {@link EfficientStorageEventHandler} is responsible for:
 * - Efficient `"storage"` event handling
 * (1 check if key is in map of observed keys per `StorageEvent`
 * and then calling correct handlers for key,
 * instead of having `key_count` checks in every event listener
 * if we should handle event with this key in current handler)
 */
export class EfficientStorageEventHandler {
  private readonly _handleStorageEvent: (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => void;

  private _observedKeyCount = 0;

  private readonly _observedKeyToStorageEventHandlerSetMap = new Map<
    string,
    Set<(storageEvent: StorageEvent) => void>
  >();

  constructor() {
    this._handleStorageEvent = (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => {
      if (storageEvent.key !== null) {
        const storageEventHandlerSet =
          this._observedKeyToStorageEventHandlerSetMap.get(storageEvent.key);

        if (isDefined(storageEventHandlerSet)) {
          for (const storageEventHandler of storageEventHandlerSet) {
            storageEventHandler(storageEvent);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // If `key` is `null`, user requested to delete all items
        this._observedKeyToStorageEventHandlerSetMap.forEach(
          (storageEventHandlerSet2) => {
            for (const storageEventHandler of storageEventHandlerSet2) {
              storageEventHandler(storageEvent);
            }
          },
        );
      }
    };
  }

  /**
   * Notice that order of events is not guaranteed,
   * and following from it, not all events may be processed at all!,
   * because see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969202/in-which-order-storage-event-is-received
   *
   * @return function which will stop listening `storageEventHandler`
   * when called
   */
  addStorageEventHandler(
    key: string,
    storageEventHandler: (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => void,
  ): () => void {
    let storageEventHandlerSet =
      this._observedKeyToStorageEventHandlerSetMap.get(key);

    if (isUndefined(storageEventHandlerSet)) {
      this._tryStartListeningStorageEvent();

      storageEventHandlerSet = new Set<(storageEvent: StorageEvent) => void>([
        storageEventHandler,
      ]);

      this._observedKeyToStorageEventHandlerSetMap.set(
        key,
        storageEventHandlerSet,
      );
    } else {
      storageEventHandlerSet.add(storageEventHandler);
    }

    // Making `storageEventHandlerSet2` `const` to tell compiler that
    // `storageEventHandlerSet2` can't change and is always defined
    const storageEventHandlerSet2 = storageEventHandlerSet;

    return () => {
      storageEventHandlerSet2.delete(storageEventHandler);

      if (storageEventHandlerSet2.size === 0) {
        this._observedKeyToStorageEventHandlerSetMap.delete(key);
        this._tryStopListeningStorageEvent();
      }
    };
  }

  private _tryStartListeningStorageEvent() {
    if (++this._observedKeyCount === 1) {
      window.addEventListener("storage", this._handleStorageEvent);
    }
  }

  private _tryStopListeningStorageEvent() {
    if (--this._observedKeyCount === 0) {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", this._handleStorageEvent);
    }
  }
}
```

If we need to combine it with `rxjs`, we can use code like

```js
const efficientStorageEventHandler = new EfficientStorageEventHandler();
const key = 'someKey'
const efficientStorageEvent$ = new Observable<StorageEvent>((subscriber) => {
  const unsubscribe = efficientStorageEventHandler.addStorageEventHandler(
    key,
    (storageEvent) => {
      subscriber.next(storageEvent);
    },
  );

  return unsubscribe;
});
```